# Search box with search information (like Stackoverflow search)

Tags: angular, primeng, search-box

I'm new to PrimeNG and I would like to implement a searchbox similar to stackoverlfows' search, where special search functionality is shown when a user clicks in the searchbox.

Has PrimeNG a component that can help me achieve this?

e.g.:
[image: Stackoverflow search]

Thanks!

Comment: you can use the OverlayPanel : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/overlaypanel

Comment: That could work, thank you!